# Viewing contents of stored procedure from PHP

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My hosting provider (JustHost) uses MySQL, and has a bizarre feature in which once you create a stored procedure through PHP MyAdmin, it can never be modified or exported again. 
[image: screenshot from php my admin]

I tried the "SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION..." from within PHP MyAdmin but it just returned null. The ONLY way to access this procedure successfully seems to be a Call. It works like a charm with no problems from within PHP MyAdmin and my application, but I cannot access the actual SQL. Is there another SQL script I can run to get the contents? Or, since it works from PHP (i.e. my application), is there a PHP function I can use to echo the contents of the stored procedure onto the browser page?

Comment: When I exported the entire database the procedures weren't there

Comment: I only have one database that I use for everything...the procedures look to be listed under that database

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use SQL (either in PHP MyAdmin or writing your own PHP script) to do this.  Use SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE  to look at the procedure's definition.  I'm not sure what version of MySQL you're using, so YMMV with this reference to the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-procedure.html

The error you're getting in that screen capture implies the SQL you ran cannot see the procedure...  Are you running it in the same database where the procedure lives?

Comment: I did "SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Calendarmonth" and it just gave me a null

Comment: Using MySQL 5.6.32-78.1

Comment: In that case, check out here:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22817/show-procedure-code-in-mysql  There's some code which may be useful when show create procedure doesn't work.  I don't have access to a MySQL box right now otherwise I'd try it out - sorry!